# Getting a basic materialize CSS dropdown to work

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to use a materialize CSS dropdown, but I am not getting the materialized version to work.

Here is what their example is (I am having this because it requires me to have a code sample to post):

```
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
  </div>
```

Here is a fiddle of the example I am trying to get to work, the first is the dropdown using the browser-default and the second is from the reference:

https://jsfiddle.net/msq3g0nk/10/

Here is a link to the doc (choose "select" on the right)

http://materializecss.com/forms.html

Any assistance would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the dropdown, as mentioned in the docs.

http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select-initialization

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/msq3g0nk/11/

Comment: Thank you for your help, I read that wrong and was thinking the materialize JS already did that for me? That also explained why the date picker wasn't working! Thanks!